# I have created new laravel project but I am getting this error

Tags: laravel

I have created new laravel project but I am getting this error

> The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host.
>
> send of 158 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! https://repo.packagist.org
>   could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the
>   local cache and may be out of date

Comment: Hi, what would you like us to do with this? :) Please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this, configure `composer` to use the `https` repository by running the following command on the `cli` before installing `Laravel`

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Comment: Great! Keep learning..and Do not forget to accept the answer.